# Accessing dom elements during d3.js select/append - creating custom tag cloud

Tags: javascript, svg, tags, d3.js

I am trying to create a word/tag cloud with d3.js where the y axis is controlled by data variables instead of the random placement like in normal word/tag clouds.  So I don't mind where the text is placed on the xaxis, but I do want control of where it is on the yaxis.

My approach was add a text element for each piece of data with the x attribute function as:

```
.attr("x", function(d,i) {
    loop 10 times
        generate random x
        loop through previous added element <i to check for collision
        no collision exit loop
    if (collision) set x to somewhere off the image
```

This method fails as I don't seem to be able to access any of the previous elements until the append has finished.

Any suggestions for a better method to do this or a way to access elements during the append?

Comment: You could place each node within a `tspan` inside a `text` parent, then randomize attr `dx`. This will always avoid collision and position your text correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a good word cloud implementation by Jason Davies which contains pretty much any customization you would like to make: http://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/#http%3A%2F%2Fsearch.twitter.com%2Fsearch.json%3Frpp%3D100%26q%3D%7Bword%7D=cloud